# What are good pollinator flowers that you need to only seed once

Tags: flowers, hardiness-zone

What are some great pollinator flowers that I can seed once to regrow between having a herd on a couple times per year in zone 4?

Comment: Hi black thumb! Would you mind explaining what you mean by having a herd on? That would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "self-pollinating"?

Comment: @NiallC. i mean something that will produce seed between having animals come have and have a meal. Sue i have animals coming through to eat grass a few times per year.

Comment: The timing of when you have cattle on the land makes a difference - no sense in planting something that will be eaten just before it flowers. Approximately what months are the cattle there?

Comment: 90-120 day cycle for livestock (think Joel Salitin, or Gabe Brown)